# Select equal number of random rows with respect to a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider I have a table like this

```
Col1 || Col2
-------------
a    ||  0
b    ||  0
c    ||  1
d    ||  1
e    ||  0
```

How can I select rows from it so that I have equal number of 1s and 0s, like below can be a result

```
Col1 || Col2
-------------
a    ||  0
c    ||  1
d    ||  1
e    ||  0
```

The rows removed/left out are at random and deleting from an existing table would work as well.

Comment: Do you want a result that has the maximum number of rows?  A result with 2 rows-- a random 1 and a random 0 would meet your requirements as written.

Comment: @JustinCave Maximum number of rows. It's actually a big table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `col2` partition, you can give each row a row number and then find those rows where there is only one instance of the row number and delete them:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT MIN(ROWID)
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
             AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
  GROUP BY rn
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
);
```

---

If you just want to `SELECT` the rows then you can use a similar technique:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rn) AS cnt
  FROM   (
    SELECT col1,
           col2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
             AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
)
WHERE cnt = 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9664dda454e059e4d312be2bbf39591f)*

Comment: The delete query preserves the order, which I loved

Answer (score 1):

use the window function to count the frequency of col2 and row number over col2. Then get the minimum frequency from it. Later get the rows with rownum less than or equal to min frequency.

```
with data AS
(
SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by col2 order by dbms_random.value()) as rownum, COUNT(*) over(partition by col2) freq from test
),
data2 as
(
  SELECT min(freq) as cnt from data 
)
SELECT col1, col2 from data,data2 where rownum <= cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I select rows from it so that I have equal number of 1s and 0s?

Yet another option might be to count `COL2` values and use *least* of those two (as the final result has to have equal number of `0`s and `1`s) in a UNION set operation. Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL1       COL2
---- ----------
a             0
b             0
c             1
d             1
e             0
```

Query & result:

```
SQL> with cnts as
  2    -- count rows by COL2 value
  3    (select sum(case when col2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_0,
  4            sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_1
  5     from test
  6    )
  7  select t.* from test t cross join cnts c
  8    where t.col2 = 0 and rownum <= least(c.cnt_0, c.cnt_1)
  9  union all
 10  select t.* from test t cross join cnts c
 11    where t.col2 = 1 and rownum <= least(c.cnt_0, c.cnt_1);

COL1       COL2
---- ----------
a             0
b             0
c             1
d             1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only one subquery/CTE.  The following returns the smaller number of `0`s and `1` (which determines the number of rows being returned):

```
least( sum(col2), sum(1 - col2) ) as num_rows
```

Then, you can incorporate this into a window function with `row_number()`:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*,
             least(sum(col2) over (), sum(1-col2) over ()) as num_rows,
             row_number() over (partition by col2 order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

This analytic function check if there are more zeroes or ones in the table

```
sum(decode(col2,0,-1,col2)) over()
```

Depending on the result use *cumulative sum* starting with that value of `col2` that appears in lower count and mapping (using `decode`) it to `-1`, the other value is mapped to `1`.

The filter is done on `cum_sum <= 0` i.e. you get the same number of `0` and `1`.

```
with t1 as (
select 
 col1, col2, 
 case when sum(decode(col2,0,-1,col2)) over() <= 0 then
      /* more zeroes */
      sum(decode(col2,0,1,1,-1)) over(order by col2 desc, col1)  
 else     
      sum(decode(col2,0,-1,col2)) over(order by col2  , col1) 
 end  as cum_sum
from  tab)
select col1, col2 
from t1
where cum_sum <= 0;
```